# logrus mqtt hook not sending logs to topic - golang

Tags: go, mqtt, tls1.2, logrus

I want to use logrus hooks in golang project to send logs on MQTT topic, I have a message broker `"tls://wwww-xxx.yyyyy.zzzzzzzzzzz"`, I'm using below code from this [doc](https://github.com/shirou/logrusmqtt) to test it with my broker, this code runs without any error and also I can see logs in console but no logs sent on topic.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"

    "github.com/shirou/logrusmqtt"
)

func main() {
    log := logrus.New()

    p := logrusmqtt.MQTTHookParams{
        Hostname:   "wwww-xxx.yyyyy.zzzzzzzzzzz",
        Topic:      "logrusmqtt/log",
        Port:       8883,
        CAFilepath: "/vvv/www/xxxxx/yyyyy/zzzzz-zzzzz/ca.crt",
    }

    hook, err := logrusmqtt.NewMQTTHook(p, logrus.DebugLevel)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    log.Hooks.Add(hook)

    log.Info("Info message")

    log.WithFields(logrus.Fields{
        "name": "joe",
        "age":  42,
    }).Error("Error Message with fields")
}
```

I subscribed for topic using mosquitto (below command) to verify if messages being sent

```
mosquitto_sub -h wwww-xxx.yyyyy.zzzzzzzzzzz -p 8883 -t logrusmqtt/log/# --cafile /vvv/www/xxxxx/yyyyy/zzzzz-zzzzz/ca.crt -d
```

And just to be sure broker is working properly, I sent a test message using command line and it's working, subscriber receives test message.

```
mosquitto_pub -h wwww-xxx.yyyyy.zzzzzzzzzzz -p 8883 -m "Pub test message" -t logrusmqtt/log --cafile /vvv/www/xxxxx/yyyyy/zzzzz-zzzzz/ca.crt -d
```

But it doesn't work with logrus hook.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to add a `time.Sleep(time.Second*5)` at the end. Maybe the application ends before sending any action?

Comment: The plugin you are using [does not wait](https://github.com/shirou/logrusmqtt/blob/master/hook.go#L65) for the connection to come up (calling `token.Error()` like this is fairly pointless; `token.Wait()` needs to be called first). So I'd say @slsy is right (the MQTT publish happens asynchronously).

Comment: I raised an issue after making the above comment and it's [already been addressed](https://github.com/shirou/logrusmqtt/pull/4) (however the `Publish` is still async so if you exit immediately it may not have been transmitted).

Comment: Great, #slsy was right, after updating package with @Brits's fix, it's working now.